# Issue regarding pdfkit and wkhtmltopdf in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I want to create a pdf file of a webpage or with some custom text in my ruby on rails application. So I am trying to run a standalone ruby program for testing.
But the execution is terminated unexpectedly showing the following error.

cannot load such file -- wkhtmltopdf (LoadError)

But I have placed both the files wkhtmltopdf-amd64 and wkhtmltopdf-i386 in the same folder. But my computer has Intel core i5 processor. So do I need to place any other wkhtmltopdf binary file suitable for my machine? If so please tell me about the download source.

My code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "pdfkit"
require 'wkhtmltopdf'
require 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'

kit = PDFKit.new(<<-HTML)
 <p>Hello Envato!</p>
HTML

kit.to_file("hello.pdf")
```

I do not know why I am getting this error. Please help me to figure out this.
And lastly if the webpage contains any image then can I convert it into pdf in same manner?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you `gem install wkhtmltopdf`? Did you follow install instructions of wkhtmltopdf respectively? What does `which wkhtmltopdf`output in a terminal? What system are you on (OSX? Linux? Windows)?

Comment: I have mentioned require wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltopdf-binary gem in my code. Is that not enough? if not then please help me to figure out how to install it properly. I have windows 8.1 64bit platform. but later I have to deploy it to heroku. Then how to mange stuffs there?

Comment: yes, I installed it using the command 'gem install wkhtmltopdf'

Comment: Have you followed [PDFKit Installation](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#install) and [Configuration](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit#configuration)?  I found it hard sometimes to get PDFKit running properly with the correct version of wkhtml (pdfkit-installed gem dependency vs. system) but never experienced missing it entirely, beyond I'm not aware of any windows specific stuff.

Comment: also had issues with these in windows, tried the gem prawn which works well and has fantastic documentation and never looked back

Comment: @peter can you refer me the prawn documentation guide link?